# postgres-operator Failed to connect to database

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have installed https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator on my K8S cluster on namespace **postgres**

```
helm install postgres-operator -n postgres ./charts/postgres-operator 
helm install postgres-operator-ui -n postgres ./charts/postgres-operator-ui
```

and have created a database as follows:

```
kind: "postgresql"
apiVersion: "acid.zalan.do/v1"

metadata:
  name: "acid-databaker-db"
  namespace: "dev"
  labels:
    team: acid

spec:
  teamId: "acid"
  postgresql:
    version: "12"
  numberOfInstances: 2
  volume:
    size: "5Gi"
  users:
    admin: []
  databases:
    keycloak: admin
  allowedSourceRanges:
    # IP ranges to access your cluster go here

  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 100Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 500Mi
```

The database instances are up and running on **namespace dev**:

```
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
acid-databaker-db          ClusterIP   10.245.205.143   <none>        5432/TCP   10h
acid-databaker-db-config   ClusterIP   None             <none>        <none>     10h
acid-databaker-db-repl     ClusterIP   10.245.152.182   <none>        5432/TCP   10h
```

And the output of Postgres service:

```
Name:              acid-databaker-db
Namespace:         dev
Labels:            application=spilo
                   cluster-name=acid-databaker-db
                   spilo-role=master
                   team=acid
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.245.205.143
Port:              postgresql  5432/TCP
TargetPort:        5432/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.1.49:5432
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I also tried to connect to the created database via PSQL client on from my local computer as follows:

```
export PGMASTER=$(kubectl get pods -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name} -l application=spilo,cluster-name=acid-databaker-db,spilo-role=master)
export PGPASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret  postgres.acid-databaker-db.credentials.postgresql.acid.zalan.do -o 'jsonpath={.data.password}' | base64 -d)

kubectl port-forward $PGMASTER 5432:5432
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5432 -> 5432
Forwarding from [::1]:5432 -> 5432
```

and I tried to connect to db and list all the created db:

```
psql (12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \dt
            List of relations
 Schema |     Name     | Type  |  Owner   
--------+--------------+-------+----------
 public | postgres_log | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

Why does the keycloak not exist, I have created above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you missed out the database owner rights and the role for the application, here is the correct manifest:

```
kind: "postgresql"
apiVersion: "acid.zalan.do/v1"

metadata:
  name: "acid-databaker-db"
  namespace: "postgres"
  labels:
    team: acid

spec:
  teamId: "acid"
  postgresql:
    version: "12"
  numberOfInstances: 2
  volume:
    size: "5Gi"
  users:
    admin: # database owner
      - superuser
      - createdb
    keycloak: [] # role for application
  databases:
    keycloakDB: keycloak # dbname: owner

  allowedSourceRanges:
    # IP ranges to access your cluster go here

  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 100Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 500Mi
```